# C++ how to pass array of pointers to a function

Tags: c++

I need to pass an array of pointers to a function,
In the example below, there is a class called base and an array of pointers called pool.
How can I pass the array pool to a function called function?
1) in case that I want to be able to change the original array of pointers.
2) in case that I  only want to pass a copy of the array of pointers.

Thanks,

```
class base
{

};

void function (base * pool)
{

}


int main
{
    base *pool[40];

    function (pool[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you use stl? if yes, then use vector of pointers.

Comment: Hi,yes I can use STL. please explain how can it help me.

Comment: I agree with Kimi, you should use vector of pointers, since one issue with array is you've to pass it's length. Anyway you can just pass array like {function(pool);", I guess...

Comment: @user2162793 You have already received a good answer for your current problem. If you want to use vectors instead and need help using them start with the [documentation for `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), then search SO for questions you have then when you run into something you can't figure out ask another question. Another option is to use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if you have a fixed number of elements known at compile time.

Comment: Hi Captain Obvlious, I wrote this remark before I saw the other answers that are very good.

Comment: thank you for the answer about the stl, understood, I can pass the STL vector by its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class base
{
    public:
    int a;
};

void function (base ** pool)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 40; ++i)
        cout<<pool[i]->a<<' ';
}


int main()
{
    base *pool[40];

    // Allocate 40 base objects and the 40 base pointers 
    // point to them respectively    
    for(int i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
    {
        pool[i] = new base;
        pool[i]->a = i;
    }
    function (pool);


    // free the 40 objects
    for(int i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
        delete pool[i];

    return 0;
}
```

I added the `a` member just as an example.

Even better would be

```
void function (base ** pool, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n; ++i)
        cout<<pool[i]->a<<' ';
}
```

and

```
function (pool, n);
```

It's not so easy to pass a copy of the array - especially in the case where the objects itself are dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 1):

To pass an array to a function, and maintain the type information about the array, you can use a template:

```
template <unsigned N>
void function (base *(&pool)[N]) {
}
```

There is no way to pass a copy of an array, unless it is inside a `struct` or `class`. In C++11, you have such a class in STL, called `array`:

```
#include <array>
template <unsigned N>
void function (std::array<base *, N> pool) {
    pool[0] = 0;
}

base b;
std::array<base *, 40> p;
p[0] = &b;
function(p);
assert(p[0] == &b);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer it´s working, what is the meaning of the last line assert(p[0] == &b); VC2012 replies: assert identifiers not found.

Comment: You need `#include <assert.h>`. It is the C style exception before C++ was around. It raises the `SIGABRT` signal if the condition isn't true.